# What is my recourse if someone made a gmail account with my name?

Tags: gmail, identity-theft

Much of my personal information is available online. That is not a particular issue for me, but someone used my name to make a gmail account with my specific name on it (it is an unusual name), and ordered some game codes from ebay using my email address, which was somehow linked to my credit card. Visa, Ebay and paypal refunded me, but the gmail account still remains, with my home address attached to it. Google says they can do nothing to shut this down unless I file a court order. Is there anything I can do short of this? I see that there is a similar question here but it is asking something different.

Comment: So you don't have access to the Gmail account, they just used your name to create it?

Comment: yes. I emailed the owner, and of course nothing happened. They might have even abandoned it, after they got their items. Still, it is in my name, and it is unique.

Comment: Similar question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93055/how-to-track-who-created-a-fake-gmail-account-using-my-name?rq=1

Comment: Why do you want this email shut down?

Comment: It's mainly because it is the only gmail account out there with my name on it, and I do public work. But also, these kinds of frauds might be easier with this gmail account, that's all.

Comment: as I said above, I saw that there was a similar question, but it had different concerns. sorry.

Comment: You cannot have an email address shut down simply because the name is the same as yours.

Comment: Likely, someone got a copy of your card.  They created the g-mail account matching the name on the card.  They created an ebay account using this g-mail account.  They ordered the game codes through ebay using the credit card.  Now that you have a new card and the old card disabled, this string of accounts has no connection to you and no way for them to reconnect without stealing your new card.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not that someone made a free email account with your name. There are hundreds of "John Smith"s, "Jay Kim"s, and "Maria Garcia"s with that issue, and they manage to live just fine.

Your issue is "which was somehow linked to my credit card". Focus on finding out how that happened, and fixing it and then let the email account worries be a distant second worry compared to that.

It is very unlikely that you will succeed in getting the account disabled unless you can prove some fraud activities are taking place.

Comment: There was fraud, and they gave me a new credit card. The police were called and they said that they see this all the time. No one seems to worry. It is strange to me.

Comment: It is less "not worried" and more "nothing we can do".